# Is it possible to use post method in catalog advanced search form?

Tags: advanced-search, toolbar

The idea is to keep the form in catalogsearch/advanced/

and to post the result to catalogsearch/advanced/result/

without all parameters added by the get method.

What are the necessary changes to have toolbar working ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things here.

### 1. Change Form Method to `POST`

File : `app\design\frontend\{package|\{theme}\template\catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml`

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSearchPostUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
```

Here we just changed form action method to `POST`.

### 2.Rewrite controller `Mage_CatalogSearch_AdvancedController`

To do this in proper way, you have to create a small module. Let me call it as `MagentoSE_CatalogSearch`.

File : `app\code\local\MagentoSE\CatalogSearch\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <catalogsearch>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <magentose_catalogsearch before="Mage_CatalogSearch">MagentoSE_CatalogSearch</magentose_catalogsearch>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </catalogsearch>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

File : `app\code\local\MagentoSE\CatalogSearch\controllers\AdvancedController.php`

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_CatalogSearch').DS.'AdvancedController.php');
 
class MagentoSE_CatalogSearch_AdvancedController extends Mage_CatalogSearch_AdvancedController
{
    public function resultAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        try {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->addFilters($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirectError(
                Mage::getModel('core/url')
                    ->setQueryParams($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                    ->getUrl('*/*/')
            );
        }
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Change here is obvious. Instead of `$this->getRequest()->getQuery()`, we are now using `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` to fetch form data correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please give changes needed to have toolbar working properly ? Actually not working with changes given in your answer.

Comment: @Jordan My answer is just hint. You need to have min. knowledge about Magento module development. You should study it if not. This is a platform to learn, not a platform to get code snippets or extension :)

Comment: I agree with you. what I know is that get method send parameters to url and toolbar.php return current url with rewrites and additional parameters. As post method don't send parameters to url, toolbar.php need changes.